# What does "use 'hg update' to get a consistent checkout" mean?

Tags: merge, mercurial

I accidentally ran `hg update featurebranch` while my working directory had changes. When it asked me to resolve merge conflicts on the first file, I immediately pressed Ctrl-C to kill the command. Now when I try to commit I get the error:

```
abort: last update was interrupted
(use 'hg update' to get a consistent checkout)
```

What does that mean and how do I recover from this situation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`hg update -r .` will do a no-op update to the working branch without changing any files and fix the error message.

<sub>I'm not entirely sure how/why it works, so if someone explains that I will accept their answer.</sub>

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but `.` is a synonym of the parent of the current state. If you are not issuing a `-C` with the update, I assume you are truly executing a no-op. However, the good side of it is that it also tells Mercurial that the update completed successfully, resetting the `interrupted` state.